# Different base point in Curve25519 in signal protocol?

Tags: cryptography, libsodium, curve-25519, signal-protocol

I have been studying [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) and [signal protocol](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/) since few days .
What i came to know that in general Curve25519 uses "9" as base point but in signal base point used is convert_mont(9). convert_mont(9) is the function which generate a twisted edward curve key pair using montgomery private key as the parameter. Why is that?

Also it has been mentioned that in the docs that

```
XEd25519 signatures are valid Ed25519 signatures [1] and vice versa, provided the public keys are converted with the birational map.
```

which i think means that if Ed25519 signatures are calculated using convert_mont() then it is equivelent to the XEd25519 signature .

If i have to implement convert_mont() then how do i do airthmetic operation on in libsodium since i am pretty new to cryptography.

Thanks.

Comment: The folks on the [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) can probably answer in detail. Just a guess since I did not look at the code... The protective coordinates are converted to a Montgomery representation. The Montgomery representation allows use of a Montgomery Ladder for near-constant time multiplication. I do know the various Bernstein-derived implementations perform an expand step from the little-endian byte array to a base-51 polynomial, but that should have already occurred. See the function `curve25519_expand`.

Comment: @jww well the main confusion was to understand the  signature scheme. Since if i use the convert_mont(9) as a curve parameter then the signatures will be different and i think XEd25519 is their name . So is it ok to use the the normal Curve25519 with base point 9 in their protocol .